# recyclerview and some view in nestedscrollview

Tags: nestedscrollview

In XML with attachments NeastedScrollView put him in LinearLayout but LinearLayout telescope ImageVew and underneath RecyclerView.

Thing is when you start something LINKS RecyclerView focuses on the full screen scrolling Upper ImageVew up. RecyclerView automatically starts with a need to with beginning begins with pictures.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView        
    <LinearLayout         
        <ImgeView                       
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView        
<LinearLayout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"       
    <ImgeView                       
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
</LinearLayout>
```